# Does anyone know what this set of aviation wings signifies?

Tags: pilots

I stumbled upon this set of aviation wings whilst searching through a box of old things, though I'm at a loss as to their origin, and what they symbolise.

Judging from the lack of skill used to craft the item (Seems the mold had an off day), I doubt it's rare, though I could, very likely, be wrong.

Other than what you can see in the picture, the wings are roughly two inches long, and made of metal; sterling silver, perhaps?

As for background information, I did have Polish family who fought during WW2 in the west, and another who served in the RAF Regiment. There really isn't much else I can tell you, so I apologise for the ambiguity.

Still, I hope you can help!

[image: Resized]

[image: Rear]

Comment: Asked in the History exchange, and added a clearer image.

Comment: Looks like German eagle for me

Comment: no, please don't ask the same question on two sites at the same time!

Comment: @Notts90 not necessarily, in Italy signifies "military" vs "civilian" eagle

Comment: What material is the blue part on the back?